# Flask Python App - Memory issues

Tags: python, memory-management, flask

I built a flask web app that manipulates big dataframes.
Each time I make a call to the url, the used RAM of the server increase of 2Gb.

But if I kill the browser session, the server used RAM does not decrease (no clear of the used memory) --> it ends with a memory error.

The structure of the code is the following :

```
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask,render_template,request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/index", methods = ['GET','POST'])
def index():
      global df
      df2 = df.copy()
      #...data treatment on df2 depending on POST parameters...#
      return render_template('template.html', df2 = df2.to_html())

df = pd.read_csv("path_to_huge_dataframe")
app.run(debug=True,threaded=True)
```

I canot load the dataframe in the index() function because it takes several minutes because of the size of the file. So I use a 'global' variable but I think it is the reason of my problem.

Comment: What is `global df` doing? Is this complete code or just a mockup?

Comment: `read_csv()` has a ton of parsing options to reduce the resulting size. That's probably your issue... without that it'll use `object` as the dtype for many fields and your memory will explode.

Comment: It's complete code, the global df is here to load the dataframe once for all at the start of the app.
What parsing options have you in mind ?

Comment: Hi @Phil27, I realize this is 3 years late!! :P But I got to ask, was the reason to store the dataframe in a global variable is so that it's available for retrieval in different views? (i.e. pages).

Comment: Hi @JackSparrow123, 3 years late for me as well ! But the answer is yes.